# Make hash value reserved

Tags: hash, hashcode

I need to use an existing (C++) hash function which creates 32 bit hash values for given keys.
The function is extremely complicated.

Now I need to have one value reserved, i.e. so the hash function will never output this value.

Is there a safe way of doing so without understanding/changing complex logic of the existing hash function?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach if you want a hash function which will never return zero:

```
int result;

hash = compute_hash_one_way();  // Hopefully it's not zero
if (hash) return hash;          // In which case we return it
hash = compute_hash_another_way(); // Try something else
if (hash) return hash;             // If that was good, return that
return 8675309; // We know THAT's not zero
```

The second hash computation need not be anything fancy; basically, if one has available any non-zero value that kinda-sorta depends on the input, one may as well use it in preference to returning a constant, but it would likely be better to use a really crummy fast hash function (or even simply always return a constant if the original returned zero) than spend so much time computing the second hash that outside code might infer that the original hash was zero.  Note that if the original hash is good, even returning a constant when the original hash returns zero will only cause that constant to be returned for one in two billion inputs rather than one in four billion.

[Incidentally, if I had written the specs for GetHashCode or hashcode in .NET/Java, I would have strongly recommended that a good hash function should only return zero if it could do so essentially instantaneously.  The extra time required to e.g. have `Integer.GetHashCode()` never return zero would in most cases exceed any time that might be spent calling `GetHashCode` redundantly on the value zero, but something like a string hash which returns zero can on some occasions have major performance implications.]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need 'optional' keys. You'd then do

```
hash = hash_combine(has_value()? 1 : 0, has_value()? hash(value()) : 0);
```

Alternatively, if you insist, you could reduce the number of bits to 31

```
compromised_hash = SHIFT_RIGHT(raw_hash) ^ raw_hash; // just an example.
```

Now, the MSB will always be empty. If it is not: you have your special marker. It would not be easy to make this so that it reduces hash domain by only 1 element (unless you can change the hash raw function)

Comment: Thanks, good idea with shifting to 31 bits, but the first solution with optional keys I did not really understand. What do has_value() and value() do?

Comment: Since you didn't tag as any particular language, it is pseudo code for an 'optional' type (I'm assuming you might want to represent "no value" as hash 0, but in fact any 'special' case can be handled the same way). C++ would have `boost::optional`, C# `System.Nullable<T>`. Etc. IOW: an example of 'special case detection'